# FlexBox in JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Open Inn Management Site</title>
<link href="http://www.openjs.com/scripts/ui/calendar/calendar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.flexbox.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexbox.min.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $.ready(function() {   
        alert("welcome");
        $('#fb').flexbox('json.jsp');   
    });  
</script> 

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="http://www.openjs.com/scripts/ui/calendar/calendar.js"></SCRIPT>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/1.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />

</head>

<body>

                <div id="fb">
                    <input type="hidden" id="fb_hidden" name="fb" value="">
                    <input id="fb_input" autocomplete="off" class="fb-input watermark" style="width: 183px; ">
                    <span id="fb_arrow" class="fb-arrow out"></span>
                    <div id="fb_ctr" style="width: 202px; top: 22px; left: 0px; display: none; " class="fb">
                    <div class="content"></div>
                    <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

and the following json.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page contentType="application/json" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%
  int i=1;
  String s="test";
  String a="{\"results\":[{\"id\":"+i+",\"name\":\""+s+"\"}]}";
  System.out.println(a);
%>

</body>
</html>
```

All the directory of the css and js are correct... question is why is it now showing a combo box? What am I doing wrong here? I think the ready function is not called because the alert doesn't shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. You need `$(document).ready()` instead of `$.ready()` (as instructed in so many jQuery tutorials).

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
       $(document).ready(function() {   
           alert("welcome");
           $('#fb').flexbox('json.jsp');   
       });  
   </script>
   ```

   Otherwise it will be called *before* the document is ready loading, when the element with `id="fb"` may not be there yet.
2. You're intermixing HTML and JSON in a single response. Get rid of the HTML clutter. HTML is not JSON.
3. You're writing JSON to system out only (which ends up in stdout and/or server log file), not to the response body. Replace `System.out.println()` by `out.print()`. The complete JSP should look like this:

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %><%
       int i = 1;
       String s = "test";
       String a = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":" + i + ",\"name\":\"" + s + "\"}]}";
       out.print(a);
   %>
   ```

   *(ensure that there are no newlines between `%>` and `<%`!)*

   Actually, the JSP is the wrong place for this job. Use a Servlet.

Comment: I did all the changes above and still... the same thing

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else. Debug the HTTP request using Firebug. What happens and what happens not? Are all styles and scripts loaded properly? Are all scripts executed without errors? Etcetera. In the future, please do not change the code in the question. Now my answer makes no sense. I've rollbacked the edit.